# Java - How to pull the list position as an integer?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm trying to get my code to pull all the values of my index that match. I currently do not know how to pull the positional value of the list (like if it's in position 0, 1, 2, 3, etc) based off of whether it contains the corresponding value entered.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test086 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();


        int userIn = 0;
        System.out.println("Please provide your own array of numbers. Hit enter again to exit the program.");

        while (true) {
            userIn = Integer.valueOf(user.nextLine());
            if (userIn == -1) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                array.add(userIn);
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Search for? ");
        int index = Integer.valueOf(user.nextLine());
        int indSize = array.size() - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            if (index == array.get(i)) {
                System.out.print(index + " is at index ");
            }
             System.out.println(indSize);
        }
    }
}
```

If I typed in my program for my list:

```
72
2
8
8
11
-1

Search for? 8
```

My expectations is to get this as an output:

```
8 is at index 2
8 is at index 3
```

What is it that I don't know? Is there some way you can check the position and pull it similar to the for loop that I have?

Comment: Check this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-index-of-an-array-element-in-java/

Comment: `System.out.print(index + " is at index " + i);`

Comment: @Kon haha wow! I totally see it now. For some reason I didn't realize that when my index variable and array.get(i) were equaled in the boolean spot that the index position would hold at that time of being pulled until it got incremented again. Thanks!

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger no problem! A great takeaway lesson here is to try to maintain in the working memory of your brain the various scoped variables and their states. Even small variables should have a place in the mental model you build in your mind of any function. Good luck!

Comment: @mightymorphinParkRanger - you should also take care a few things mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583899/java-how-to-pull-the-list-position-as-an-integer/60588569#60588569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print the value of `i` in your `for` loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    if (index == array.get(i)) {
        System.out.println(index + " is at index " + i);
    }
}
```

In addition to this, I also recommend you use generics e.g. `List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>()` instead of `ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>()`. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) to learn more about it.

Another recommendation is to do exception handling for the cases when the user enters an invalid value.

**Complete program:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test086 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int userIn = 0;
        System.out.println("Please provide your own array of numbers. Hit enter again to exit the program.");

        while (true) {
            try {
                userIn = Integer.parseInt(user.nextLine());
                if (userIn == -1) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    array.add(userIn);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
            }
        }

        int index = 0;
        boolean valid;
        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Search for? ");
            try {    
                index = Integer.valueOf(user.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            if (index == array.get(i)) {
                System.out.println(index + " is at index " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please provide your own array of numbers. Hit enter again to exit the program.
72
2
a
Invalid input. Try again.
abc
Invalid input. Try again.
8
8
11
-1
Search for? a
Invalid input. Try again.
Search for? x
Invalid input. Try again.
Search for? 8
8 is at index 2
8 is at index 3
```

In order to make the program modular, I also recommend factoring the user input into a separate method (e.g. `int getIntInput(Scanner)`) as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test086 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int userIn = 0;
        System.out.println("Please provide your own array of numbers. Hit enter again to exit the program.");
        while (true) {
            userIn = getIntInput(in);
            if (userIn == -1) {
                break;
            } else {
                list.add(userIn);
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Search for? ");
        int index = getIntInput(in);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (index == list.get(i)) {
                System.out.println(index + " is at index " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    static int getIntInput(Scanner in) {
        boolean valid;
        int n = 0;
        do {
            valid = true;
            try {
                n = Integer.valueOf(in.nextLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);
        return n;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Please provide your own array of numbers. Hit enter again to exit the program.
72
2
a
Invalid input. Try again.
abc
Invalid input. Try again.
8
8
11
-1
Search for? x
Invalid input. Try again.
8
8 is at index 2
8 is at index 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (index == array.get(i)) {
            System.out.print(index + " is at index " + i); // change here
        }
         System.out.println(indSize);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

List has a method for this. It lets you get the index for an object.  It returns the index of the first value encountered that matches. There are two ways to approach this using this feature.  Both use the `sublist` feature of list.

The first method gets the `lastIndexOf` method to get the index.  The advantage of this is that when the sublist is created, it doesn't change the normal position of the next item.  The disadvantage is that the indices are obtained in reverse order.

```
        List<Integer> vals =
                new ArrayList<>(List.of(10, 20, 1, 9, 10, 55, 9, 9, 9));

        int selection = 9;
        for (;;) {
            int idx = vals.lastIndexOf(selection);
            if (idx < 0) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(selection + " located at index " + idx);
            vals = vals.subList(0, idx);
        }
```

This next method, uses `indexOf` to get the value.  To ensure the indices are correct, some bookkeeping needs to be done allow for the shortened sublists.

```
        vals = new ArrayList<>(List.of(10, 20, 1, 9, 10, 55, 9, 9, 9));
        int lastIndex = 0;
        for (;;) {
            int idx = vals.indexOf(selection);
            if (idx < 0) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(selection + " located at index "
                    + (idx + lastIndex));
            idx++;
            lastIndex += idx;
            vals = vals.subList(idx, vals.size());
        }
```

Finally, again using `indexOf`, if it's okay to mutate the supplied list, all one needs to do is replace the current value with a different one so it won't be found again.

```
        vals = new ArrayList<>(List.of(10, 20, 1, 9, 10, 55, 9, 9, 9));

        for (;;) {
            int idx = vals.indexOf(selection);
            if (idx < 0) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(selection + " located at index "
                    + idx);
            vals.set(idx, selection + 1); // modify selection
        }
```